# For a positive definite matrix $A$, how to prove that $\| Ax \| \geq \lambda_1 \| x \|$?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a positive definite matrix $A$, how to prove that  $\| Ax \| \geq \lambda_1 \| x \|$ where $\lambda_1$ is the minimum eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Use \| instead of \parallel for norms.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is PSD then so is $A - \lambda_1 I$. Using the PSD definition on $A-\lambda_1 I$, we have 
$$x^T (A - \lambda_1 I) x > 0$$
for all $x$. Expand and re-arrange, we get
$$x^T A x > \lambda_1 x^T x$$
But $x^T A x < \Vert Ax \Vert \Vert x \Vert$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz and $x^Tx = \Vert x \Vert ^2$ so
$$\Vert Ax \Vert \Vert x \Vert > \lambda_1 \Vert x \Vert ^2$$
or
$$\Vert Ax \Vert > \lambda_1 \Vert x \Vert $$

Comment: It seems to me that your first sentence assumes the very thing that we want to prove.

Comment: @TonyK dang it. I was just typing something very similar. Fully agreed. That statement isn't true for an arbitrary $\lambda_1$, after all..

Comment: @TonyK how ? I thought we're proving $\Vert Ax \Vert > \lambda_1 \Vert x \Vert$

Comment: I see no problem with this answer. It starts basically by the observation that for general A, b, the eigenvalues of A-bI are the eigenvalues of A, shifted by b, and deduces $A-\lambda_1 I$ has non-negative eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

We have $ 0 \le \lambda_1 = \min \{ \frac{\langle Ax,x \rangle }{\|x\|^2} \  : \ x \in \mathbb{R} \}$. Hence

$$ \lambda_1 \| x\|^2 \le x^T Ax\le \|Ax\| \cdot \|x\|.$$

The last $ \le$ " is Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is positive definite, then $A-\lambda_1 I$ is semi positive definite since the eigenvalues of $A-\lambda_1 I$ are $\lambda_i - \lambda_1$ which are nonnegative. Then use the definition of semi positive definiteness in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definiteness_of_a_matrix
then use cauchy schwartz inequality finally you will get the result.